# how to write a getawaiter for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, async-await, task

I have a program in vb.net (VS 2017) using 4.7 framework, where a function is taking too long to process, interrupting message pumping and causing a timeout error.  To solve this I want to run the function asynchronously, using tasks and await.  (new to me).  I understand that to do that I need to create an asynchronous function (using the async keyword) which uses await to call another asynchronous function which then does the processing. The problem is how to make my own function asynchronous, which internally uses no predefined asynchronous process called by await.  To do that it seems I need to have a GetAwaiter defined for my function making it callable using await.  Here is where I get stumped.  I have searched the web, and looked for books to cover this topic, and I come up short.  All the web examples are in C# (which I am not very conversant in), and I can't wrap my head around the C# code examples I have found for creating a GetAwaiter.  As an example, from a blog by Stephen Toub there is this:

```
public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset) 
{ 
    return (dateTimeOffset – DateTimeOffset.UtcNow).GetAwaiter(); 
}
```

to create a GetAwaiter for the DateTimeOffset function.  I don't understand the  declarative line, specifically the TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter twin and the contents of the parenthesis following the GetAwaiter keyword.  I do think that 'this' refers to sender in vb, DateTimeOffset is the name of the function getting the GetAwaiter, and dateTimeOffset is a value being passed, but I don't understand that combination of function names and values inside a paren.  How can this line be rewritten in vb?   Are there any good, comprehensive books, articles, etc covering the task/await functionality - particularly when you have to create a new asynchronous function, one that is not pre-packaged and included as part of .net, and written including vb examples. I found a very informative youtube presentation by Michael Kennedy, but as in all other examples I've found, it relies on a predefined async function that can be called using await.  I need to get my head above water - which way is the surface?

Comment: The code snippet you shared seems fishy to me. The `this` keyword means the function is an extension method. Subtracting `DateTimeOffsets` returns a `TimeSpan`, which does not have a built in `GetAwaiter` method. Also, that's not exactly the kind of method you would need to make async.

Comment: Also, you really only want to make methods async if there's a reason to make them async (e.g. hitting a db, making a network call, hitting disk, waiting for a timer). With the I/O stuff, generally you'll be using a library that has it built in already - most I/O is already async at the OS level.

Comment: For me this is just a framework for how to create a GetAwaiter, the actual functionality is immaterial to me, as I would be using my own code.  I'm most interested in how this framework can be written in VB, so I can create GetAwaiters as necessary to cover time-consuming processes.  Thanks for the info on the this keyword, I'll research that and learn something.

Comment: Well, I came up with a solution - not the one I wanted, but one that seems to overcome my largest obstacle, that of being able to run a non-async function that does not rely on await internally, within an async-await structure.  I provided for passing in values and returning a value - in this case passing in a string and returning a boolean.  I ended up using a task.run call - see next comment

Comment: In the main routine I made it async, and called an async function using await  Private Async Sub MyProgAsync()   dim aBool as boolean = await myFuncAsync(string)    Inside that function I used task.run:   private Async Function myFuncAsync(byval pcValue as string) as boolean     dim lReturn as boolean = await Task(of Boolean).Run(Function() myTask(pcValue)    Return lReturn

Comment: This allowed me to call myTask, passing in a string parameter, and returning a boolean response that passed up and down the chain, and myTask is not Async and does not use an await.  Nonetheless the main program launches the chain into a new thread, while keeping the UI thread active.  I still want to learn how to write a GetAwaiter for a function I might write so that I can call it directly using await rather than using task.run.  Any suggestions as to books, articles, videos etc (using vb if possible) would be highly appreciated.